# Logic Identity for $\mathcal{(A'B)}$+$\mathcal{(AB')}$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra

I need to **simplify** a long boolean expression and I am stuck with this expression
$$\mathcal{(A'B)}\text{+}\mathcal{(AB')}$$
Can I simplify that to $\mathcal{(AB)'}\large\text{ ?} $
And if so, what principle does that use$\large\text{ ?}$

Comment: No guy, you can't

Comment: That is actually the xor gate, it can be written as A $\oplus$ B

Comment: xor gate, but does that mean i can't simplify it more?

Comment: How could it get simpler than "A (some operation) B"? anything else would have $0$ operators and so would be just A or just B, neither of which is same as what you start with.

Answer (score 1):

No, both of your expressions are **not equivalent**. We can show this by **Truth Table.**

Since, $2$ variables are there, and both of these variables can assume $2$ values $[0/1]$.
Therefore, we can have $4$ possible combinations.

In general, if **$n$ variables** are there, we can have **$2^n$ possible combinations.**

Now, **TRUTH TABLE**

| $\mathcal{A}$ | $\mathcal{B}$ | $\mathcal{A'}$ | $\mathcal{B'}$ | $\mathcal{A'B}$+$\mathcal{AB'}$ | $\mathcal{AB}$ | $\mathcal{(AB)'}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $1$ | $1$ | $\LARGE{0}$ | $0$ | $\LARGE{1}$ |
| $0$ | $1$ | $1$ | $0$ | $\LARGE{1}$ | $0$ | $\LARGE{1}$ |
| $1$ | $0$ | $0$ | $1$ | $\LARGE{1}$ | $0$ | $\LARGE{1}$ |
| $1$ | $1$ | $0$ | $0$ | $\LARGE{0}$ | $1$ | $\LARGE{0}$ |

As it is clear from table, both the columns are not same for all possible combinations.

Hence, the expressions are not equivalent.