# Karnaugh map and boolean simplification yield unsatisfactory results.[Solved]

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

My binary logic for my circuit is \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} A &B &C &D &Hallway &Stairs\\\hline
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1\\
0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &1 &1 &X &X\\
0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0\\
0 &1 &0 &1 &X &X\\
0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &1 &1 &X &X\\
1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1\\
1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0\\
1 &0 &1 &0 &X &X\\
1 &0 &1 &1 &X &X\\
1 &1 &0 &0 &X &X\\
1 &1 &0 &1 &X &X\\
1 &1 &1 &0 &X &X\\ 
1 &1 &1 &1 &X &X\\\hline
\end{array}

The expression for the hallway is$$ \bar A\bar B\bar C D  + \bar A\bar BC\bar D + \bar A B \bar C\bar D + A\bar B \bar C\bar D $$
simplified after a week of brute force guessing is $$ \bar A D + \bar BC + B\bar C+ A\bar D  $$

Karnaugh map turned out \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\large CD\backslash AB\normalsize &00 &01 &11 &10 \\\hline
00 &0 &1 &0 &1 \\
01 &1 &0 &0 &0 \\
11 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
10 &1 &0 &0 &0 \\\hline
\end{array}

The reason why I couldn't come to a simplification normally, is I kept coming to the snipet $ \bar A \bar D (B \bar C + \bar BC )$ minus the $\bar A \bar D $ , the 2 expressions in parenthesis is a XOR gate. Which I then tried substituting that for $ \bar A \bar D (B + C) (\bar B + \bar C). $ But didn't help me much. This was apparent in a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061327/abab-logic-indentity) answered very blantantly from Mauro ALLEGRANZA "**No guy, you can't**"

**Question: Explain to me as if I were a beginner, on how to simplify $ \bar A\bar B\bar C D  + \bar A\bar BC\bar D + \bar A B \bar C\bar D + A\bar B \bar C\bar D $. Adding what Boolean Theorems you used. Please and thanks.**

Comment: What you want isn't too clear. Do you mean how to get expression $\bar A D + \bar BC + B\bar C+ A\bar D$ with the K-map containing the initial information of the Hallway column (with the Xs, because they have disappeared in your desired K-map) ?

Comment: Question has been edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question: Explain to me as if I were a beginner, on how to simplify $\bar A\bar B\bar C D + \bar A\bar BC\bar D + \bar A B \bar C\bar D + A\bar B \bar C\bar D$.**

The simple answer is: **you don't.**

The expression
$\bar A\bar B\bar CD + \bar A\bar BC\bar D 
 + \bar AB\bar C\bar D + A\bar B\bar C\bar D$
is already as simple as it can get in disjunctive normal form. Other standard forms are not significantly better.

You could write it as
$\bar A\bar B(\bar C D + C\bar D) + (\bar A B + A\bar B) \bar C\bar D$.

$\bar A\bar B\bar CD + \bar A\bar BC\bar D 
 + \bar AB\bar C\bar D + A\bar B\bar C\bar D$
is **not** equivalent to
$\bar A D + \bar BC + B\bar C+ A\bar D.$
There are numerous counterexamples; for example, if $A=0$ and $B=C=D=1$ then
$\bar A D + \bar BC + B\bar C+ A\bar D$ is true but
$\bar A\bar B\bar CD + \bar A\bar BC\bar D 
 + \bar AB\bar C\bar D + A\bar B\bar C\bar D$
is false.

The reason you can express your necessary hallway logic as
$\bar A D + \bar BC + B\bar C+ A\bar D$
is because
$\bar A\bar B\bar CD + \bar A\bar BC\bar D 
 + \bar AB\bar C\bar D + A\bar B\bar C\bar D$
is **not** your hallway logic.
The expression
$\bar A\bar B\bar CD + \bar A\bar BC\bar D 
 + \bar AB\bar C\bar D + A\bar B\bar C\bar D$
is what your hallway logic **would** be if all the $X$s in the first table in the question were changed to $0$s.

That's basically what happened in the Karnaugh map in the question. You copied the $1$s faithfully from the first table, you copied the $0$s faithfully from the first table, and then you just filled everything else in with a $0$ instead of an $X$.

A Karnaugh map that accurately represented your original circuit logic (without forcing the $X$ values to be something they don't need to be) would be this:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\large CD\backslash AB\normalsize &00 &01 &11 &10 \\\hline
00 &0 &1 &X &1 \\
01 &1 &X &X &0 \\
11 &X &X &X &X \\
10 &1 &0 &X &X \\\hline
\end{array}

That should make it a lot easier to come up with your simplified formula without having to spend a week guessing.

Comment: Question has been edited again[Solved]. 
I have to commend your answer because the OP contained an error that I overlooked at the time. Even though it existed, you gave me the benefit of the doubt, and answered accordingly.

Comment: (+1) Indeed I arrived at the same remark as in your paragraph "That's basically what..."